# Name of binary encoding scheme for integer numbers

Tags: coding-theory, encoding-scheme, binary

I once found on Wikipedia a nice technique for encoding $k \in (2^{n-1}, 2^n)$ uniformly distributed integer numbers with less then $\log_2n$ average bits/symbol, thanks to a simple to compute variable length code. Basically it used $\log_2n$ for some symbols and $\log_2n - 1$ for some others.

Unfortunately all my Googling has failed me. I recall something similar to "variable length binary", but I keep ending on VLQ which are a different beast. Since I know your memory better than mine, can you help me?

Comment: Look for *prefix code*, *prefix-free code*, *uniquely decodable code*, or *variable-length code*.

Comment: You are interested in the reverse direction of Kraft's inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique idea is perfectly described in Yuval Filmus answer. Even if slightly different, it is called [Truncated binary encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_binary_encoding) in Wikipedia. I couldn't find an original source for that, apart from a mention in a [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2015192779A1/en), in this [book](https://books.google.it/books?id=jDCaDwAAQBAJ), or in this [Google API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/compression)

Another mention can be found in the [ACM ICPC 2011–2012, Northeastern European Regional Contest, November 27, 2011](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/archive/2011/neerc-2011.pdf).

Comment: An answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885703/maximum-number-of-different-numbers-huffman-compression calls this "logarithm approximation". Alas, I can't find an original source for that synonym either.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $k = 2^{n-1} + t$, where $0 \leq t < 2^{n-1}$. Use the following to encode $z \in \{0,\ldots,k-1\}$:

- If $z < 2^{n-1}-t$ then encode $z$ as its own $(n-1)$-bit encoding.
- Otherwise, write $z = 2^{n-1}-t + 2\delta+\epsilon$, where $\delta \in \{0,\ldots,t-1\}$ and $\epsilon \in \{0,1\}$. Encode $z$ at the $(n-1)$-bit encoding of $2^{n-1}-t+\delta$ followed by $\epsilon$.

Here is an example. Let $k = 11 = 2^3+3$. The encoding is as follows:

- $0 \to 000$.
- $1 \to 001$.
- $2 \to 010$.
- $3 \to 011$.
- $4 \to 100$.
- $5 \to 1010$.
- $6 \to 1011$.
- $7 \to 1100$.
- $8 \to 1101$.
- $9 \to 1110$.
- $10 \to 1111$.

Comment: This is exactly the correct reasoning. I was also missing the name of this version of the encoding. It's [Truncated binary encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_binary_encoding), according to Wikipedia.

Answer (score -2):

Usually (a, b) is an open interval, excluding a and b, and [a, b] is a closed interval, including a and b. So $(2^{n-1}, 2^n)$ is the set of numbers from $2^{n-1} + 1$ to $2^n-1$.

To encode, subtract $2^{n-1}+1$ from a number x, leaving $0 ≤ x < 2^{n-1}-1$. There are $2^{n-1}-1$ possible numbers, each with same probability, so you can use Huffman coding for just under n-1 bits on average. To be precise, you have $2^{n-1} - 2$ numbers encoded in n-1 bits, and one number encoded in n-2 bits, for an average of $n-1-1/(2^{n-1}-1)$ bits.

You could use arithmetic coding, which would be a tiny, tiny bit shorter on average with a very good implementation, but would be much much more complicated. Not worth it in this case; possibly worth it if you had say $1.5 \cdot 2^n$ different numbers to store and storage size is *very* important to you.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question correctly. There are $k$ uniformly distributed numbers. These numbers are from $0$ to $k-1$. You cannot use entropy coding, because all of them have the same probability.